# ActiveMQ automatic Configuration file change and Re-Deployment

Tags: scripting, windows-server-2016, activemq

## How can we automate the task of a configuration file change for ActiveMQ?

### Situation:

We are running a T.A.P. street of ActiveMQ servers (5.15.7), the A and P environments are in a SAN Master Slave Configuration.

> Probably soon expanded to redundant master slaves, as the SAN is a single point of failure. (we can't afford data loss or downtime, it's medical data).

Right now whenever there is a configuration change, we (devs) have to log into these servers (windows server 2016, within V-Sphere) and manualy change the activemq.xml file to the updated state, then we have to restart the service.
On A and P we have to wait untill the first node is up before restarting node 2.

This is an error prone and time consuming process which has to be done for 5 (soon 9 ) servers. And it has to be repeated roughly every week.

### Is there tooling for managing the configuration of activeMQ?

We use ActiveMQBrowser for monitoring and administrating the Queues (moving from error or DLQ back into prod), and although we can create destinations in here, these do not propagate back into the configuration file.
Nor can we configure the server's properties from here, like timeouts.
We spent a good part of today looking into this, but have not found anything which could help.

Are there any Sysadmins on here that have had this problem? (or one like it of course)

If a script is the only way to go, could anyone provide an example? bat/ps1 scripting is not one of my strong points...

Comment: Reading back i feel like i should have started with this, but the ActiveMQ documentation does not provide answers to these questions, nor does it touch on the subject of **re** configurement.